# How to append some text to text box

Tags: javascript, html

This JavaScript checks whether the `name-text` box is empty or not.

If empty then the same line should have "Name is required" appended.

```js
function checkFields(){
  var name = document.forms["contact-form"]["name"].value;
  if(name == ""){
}
```

```html
<!--- This is the html code for text box for name and submit button to call checkFields() method -->

<div class="required-fields">
    <label>My Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="checkFields()" value="Send Message"/>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you just need `placeholder` html attribute, google it.

And, the method you chose is more likely not necessary in the first place, still check this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpdn61m9/) out,

```
     function checkFields(){
            var name = document.forms["contact-form"]["name"].value;
        console.log(name);          
        if(name == ""){

              document.getElementsByClassName('error-text')[0].innerHTML='Name field required'

              }
              else{
              document.getElementsByClassName('error-text')[0].innerHTML='';
              }
    }
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to write the error message as the value of the control.

Comment: I need it after the text box not as a value

Answer (score 0):

Try with placeHolder : or use with [input required](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_required.asp) method . if you need with append some error see the below snippet:

***Snippet:***

```js
function checkFields(){
  var name = document.forms["contact-form"]["name"].value;
  if(name =="" ){
    document.getElementById("input").placeholder = "**Name required**";
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML ="**Name required**";
}
  }
```

```html
<!--- This is the html code for text box for name and submit button to call checkFields() method -->
<form name="contact-form">
<div class="required-fields">
    <label>My Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="input" >
  <p id="error" style="color:red"></p>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="checkFields()" value="Send Message"/>
  </form>
```